# What does [-1:0] mean in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, hdl

In my code i wrote:

```
output [numSize-1:0] index;
```

`numSize` is a parameter that can be zero. What is the meaning of this? What is this gonna be synthesized to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment of output [-1:0] index would allow you to access index[-1] and index[0].

There is no preclusion to using negative values in the range of a vector in Verilog.

Comment: in other words 'index'  is just a 2-bit wire.

Comment: In the case where numSize == 0, index [numSize-1:0] is a 2 bit wire.